# SQL count how many times record has appeared before

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing `report_date` and `job_no` columns and would like to know how to return a column that shows how many times the `job_no` has appeared before the current occurrence.

I have tried count(job_no) but I do not know how to set this to only count occurrences before the current report_date.

So far, I have had to make do with exporting the data into excel and performing a countifs for report date < current report_date and job_no = current job_no but this is too clunky.

Please help! :)

Comment: before in what context... what are you sorting by.

Comment: Can you post your attempts and provide more information? Probably some sample data as well.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 2):

An analytic count may do what you are looking for:

```
select job_no
     , report_date
     , count(*) over (partition by job_no
                          order by report_date
                           rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) cnt
  from your_table
```

The windowing clause in this version will prevent counting the current row, though for the stated situation simply subtracting 1 and using the default window of `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` would be just as effective.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a correlated sub query:

```
SELECT s.job_no,(select count(*) from YourTable t
               where t.report_date < s.report_date and t.job_no = s.job_no)
FROM YourTable s
```

That way, for every job_no the correlated query will count how many occurrences were there before the current row date .

Comment: in this case a correlated sub query would be more expensive than an appropriate analytic count function.

Comment: This site is for solutions that answers the OP requests . You can't assume he has TONES of data and it will be expensive for him, and you are not suppose to downvote a correct answer because you assume yours is more correct. @Sentinel

Answer (score 1):

Just use a cumulative count:

```
select t.job_no, t.report_date,
       count(*) over (partition by t.job_no order by t.report_date) as cumecnt
from t;
```

Strictly speaking, this includes the current date so you might want to subtract 1 for *previous* listings (or use windowing clauses, which is more complicated).

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that you have a report date parameter that is fixed. In other words your comparison is not relative to any of the data in the report itself.

```
count(case when report_date < ?report_date then 1 else null end)
    over (partition by job_no)
```

If you want *do* want the count to be relative to other rows with a common `job_no` then you could do this or use @sagi's subquery approach. (I had thought Gordon made different assumptions in his answer. Looking closer I see his looks solid as usual.)

```
row_number() over (partition by job_no order by report_date) - 1
```